# calc() function for element above desired element

Tags: html, css

I have navbar with x-height and y-padding.

Now I would like to calculate how much the main div must have, to fill the whole window.

Is it possible to this in a way like this...

.something {height: calc(100vh - .navbar(height))}...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Say `35` is the sum of `height` and `padding` (top PLUS bottom) of your navbar, then your rule would be

```
.yourdiv {height: calc(100vh - 35px)}
```

But you can't use JS in there, if that is the question. But it seems you *know* the height and padding of your navbar ("x-height and y-padding"), so this would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. So if you don't know navbar height, u must use javascript?

Comment: Yep or use another option like flexbox @filtertips